# Concurrent AJAX Request and Response Function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

As I am new with AJAX learning I have a Questions That :

- Can We write concurrent AJAX `Request/Response` Functions for different Call ?
- Can I use the Same `XMLHttpRequest` Object Function in Multiple AJAX Call Functions ?`
- What If when I use the POST method in `request.Send()` Method ?

For Make Question More Simpler:
Suppose, From One AJAX call I would like to `Request/Respons`e Following Functionalities:

> 1. Check the Strength of Password
> 2. Make the Entry on DB who are Votted
> 3. Insert the record for Post a reviewed and Display the updated
>          post/review on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’d like to start by explaining what Ajax is and how we use it.
>
> **Ajax is an acronym for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.** And let’s focus on Asynchronous for a minute. This means that we can do non blocking operations while the browser can still do what it wants. And when the result is received from the Ajax request it can process it. We’ve all used it and it works fine. But have you ever tried to create a chat based on Ajax ? I did and I hit a brick wall that I couldn’t pass.
>
> Let me explain how I wanted to create the chat. I wanted to use Comet programming technique to get the new replies and normal Ajax requests to send my lines. So to be exact for the replies of other users I had an Ajax request to the server that responded if there are new replies in the chat or if it reaches 15 seconds. And to send my lines of chat I had a normal Ajax request that sends my line and responds as soon as it can.

For Detail Information : We Can check the [Link](http://lucadaniel.ro/2013/01/27/concurrent-ajax-requests-and-php/).

Comment: -1 for plagiarising text off the internet without crediting the author or specifying the source.

Comment: @Alnitak:Sorry, But Can you tell me what is "Unaccredited plagiarism" in This Answer ?

Comment: @Alnitak:Thanks For Suggestion. I have Done that.

Comment: Also, the part you've quoted doesn't seem in any way relevant to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK,

1. You can write AJAX request/response functions that are used by different (concurrent) calls
2. You can re-use the same `XMLHttpRequest` object for multiple AJAX calls, as long as they are not simultaneous
3. I don't exactly get what you are asking...

However, I suggest you to avoid using `XMLHttpRequest` and approach the AJAX technique by using some library (e.g. `jQuery`). If you are not developing a library or a framework, then you should avoid direct calls to JavaScript APIs.

Comment: For make Question Simple:Lets Take example that I have three Functions for AJAX Call and I use the Same PHP file(which are writes in req.open() method) for calling and Retrieve the data from there. So, Is it Possible or Not ?

Comment: I find it pretty obscure. Can you post an example? I'll glad to help.

Comment: Suppose, From One AJAX call I would like to Request/Response Following Functionalities: 1 - Check the Strength of Password, 2- Make the Entry on DB who are Votted 3- Insert the record for Post a reviewed.

Comment: I have No Knowledge of JQuery